# what is window.location.pathname equivalent for Next.js router?

Tags: next.js

`router.push("/login")` strips out query string params but I'd like to keep that when changing paths. `window.location.pathname` does the same so what's its equivalent for Next.js?

```js
import router from "next/router";

router.push("/login") // how to change path while keeping query string params?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `router.push` with any queries and pathname like this :

```
const router = useRouter();

router.push({
    pathname: "/other",
    query: router.query, // This get's current page query
});
```